# Emacs tempo mode does not work on the first line

Tags: templates, emacs, tempo

I'm loading tempo for Emacs:

```
(require 'tempo)
```

I can expand templates just fine, however not when the cursor is position on the beginning of the first line in the buffer.

I'm running Ubuntu with GNU Emacs 23.1.50.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.18.0)
 of 2009-09-27 on crested, modified by Debian.

How can I use templates when the file is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by switching to [YASnippet](http://code.google.com/p/yasnippet/) instead, which wins immensely in usability.